# JSyn DualOscilloscope Two open line on my sound card

Tags: java, audio, jsyn

I created a small program to record sound (I use JavaSound with TargetDataLine to reach my sound card). 
I did some testing with the class " DualOscilloscope.java " of JSYN for a visual of the sound .
The problem is that their class opens a line with " Synthesizer " so I have two line tapping on my soundcard and me that triggers an exception (as you can not open two line on a sound card).
Is it possible to use my instantiating my TargetDataLine to initialize the synthesizer of JSYN ?

[The Latest JSyn JAR File](http://www.softsynth.com/jsyn/developers/download.php)

Source code class DualOscilloscope (author Phil Burk )

```
   protected void startAudio(int itemIndex) {
  // Both stereo.
  int numInputChannels = deviceMaxInputs.get(itemIndex);
  if (numInputChannels > 2)
     numInputChannels = 2;
  int inputDeviceIndex = deviceIds.get(itemIndex);
  synth.start(16000, inputDeviceIndex, numInputChannels, AudioDeviceManager.USE_DEFAULT_DEVICE, 0);
  channel1.output.connect(pass1.input);
  // Only connect second channel if more than one input channel.
  if (numInputChannels > 1) {
     channel2.output.connect(pass2.input);
  }

  // We only need to start the LineOut. It will pull data from the
  // channels.
  scope.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSyn does not currently support being passed a TargetDataLine. You could, however, implement your own AudioDeviceManager based on the source code on GitHub. Replace JavaSoundAudioDevice.java with one that used your TargetDataLine instead of creating a new one.

An easier way would be to let JSyn open the audio input and then use that input in your program. Don't open your own TargetDataLine.

You can use JSyn to process audio or to save it as a WAVE file.  If you need to do custom processing then you could write a custom unit generator.  Or you could use an AudioStreamReader to stream the audio data to your own thread.

```
AudioStreamReader reader = new AudioStreamReader(synth, 2); // stereo
lineIn.connect(0, read.getInput(), 0);
lineIn.connect(1, read.getInput(), 1);
```

Then you can read the data from that reader instead of from your own TargetDataLine.

```
reader.read(buffer, start, count);
```

Comment: thank for your answer, I think I'll take your advice using AudioStreamReader to link with my sound card.With TargetDataLine , I recovered byte arrays containing my audio with the read method . Is it possible with AudioStreamReader because I saw an array of doubles.                                                                                                         `while (((bytesRead = targetDataLine.read(audioDataFull, 0, audioDataFull.length)) != -1) && targetDataLine.isOpen()) 
`

Comment: All of the audio data flowing between units in JSyn is double precision. Double is almost as fast as single precision. And it can make a difference if you have feedback loops because the precision errors can accumulate. 

I will think about providing a way to feed data into JSyn from outside so you could use your own hardware interface. But that could take a while. I am pretty backed up. It would be nice because you could then process audio streamed from the Internet. Please +1 if the answer works.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification , after some testing I redefined the library for take my TargetDataLine. The only problem is that with the same line I record and I display the graph and that recording is now speed I'm afraid that the vents of the library creates a bug on recording or otherwise. I'm not sure

Comment: If you give your TargetDataLine to JSyn to use then you cannot also use it. You cannot have two pieces of code, both reading from the same TargetDataLine. Each one will only get part of the data. You will need to split the stream somehow in software.

Comment: Oh all right it is annoy because I need use the same line (as I can not open two by sound card) for recording sound (my program) and display the audio signal ( Jsyn ) simultaneously.
You said separate audio stream, it is possible? While keeping all the audio data for each part ?

Comment: If you let JSyn open the TargetDataLine then the data stream can be split by using the AudioStreamReader described above.  If you open your own TargetDataLine then you would need to split the data yourself and write data into JSyn through a FIFO.

Comment: Okay, I'll open my own lines because I treated it with the bytes that I get of my TargetDataLine . So I have to fill out a " BoundedCollection < Byte> " with the bytes I receive from the line and give them to the library for me it shows the corresponding graph?
If so, where give the  FIFO, to what class ?

Comment: After some tested, the FIFO creates too much latency therefore not interested , I looked for another opportunity and I found another solution. I pass him a " DataInputStream " pointing to my under construction file and with some security and control its functions relatively well . Not as smooth as with TargetDataLine but for a start that's okay. Thank you for your help and your excellent work for the library . If there are improvements in the future I'm interested. Thank you again.